# _.sortBy an array with multiple nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, undefined, typeerror

I am trying to sort by an item location and then push that data into a table using underscorejs methods, `_.each`, `_.groupBy` and `_.sortBy`

```
sails.log('my.items.item_location.location: ', my.items[0].item_location.location)
  _.each(_.groupBy(_.sortBy(my.items.item_location.location, 'location'), 'location'), function(locationItems) {

      itemsTable.table.body.push(my.renderItemRow(locationItems));


  });
```

my `sails.log` at the top prints out data from the 0th position and I can verify that the rest of array contains defined locations.

my object:

```
my.items:[  
   {  
      "p_item_id":79,
      "uid":"9c2073da-2945-4e0d-ad97-39db1a4cde16",
      "quantity":9,
      "item_location":{  
         "inbounds_items_location_id":1,
         "uid":"fJtWsFrVD",
         "sku_uid":"150-MTG-XS",
         "location":"O8",
         "quantity":171,
      },
   },
...
]
```

whenever I access the `location` parameter I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: have you tried `_.sortBy(my.items.item_location, 'location')` from what I see you parse `location` of `item_location` you should go through `item_location`

Comment: that compiles but no data is actually printed out into the table or at least the console

Comment: that I can't help you sorry

Answer (score 0):

You should access the object in right way. Current your access `my.items.item_location.location` is wrong because `my.items` is array.
Therefore, `my.items` has no property called `item_location` but `my.items[0]` does.

In conclusion, you should write down like the below

```
_.groupBy(_.sortBy(my.items, function(item){
    return item.item_location.location
}), function(item){
    return item.item_location.location
})
```

Comment: how can i avoid returning the value and passing it along right away to the next function?

Comment: I cannot understand your comment clearly. Do you mean chaining? like `_.chain(my.items).sortBy(item => item.item_location.location).groupBy(item => item.item_location.location).value()`